# How to write an adding function that prints each number being added, up to a certain number

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

I want to create a function that will multiply each number starting from one, up to the number that is specified as a parameter in the function by itself and then add them up together to the parameter number, the trick is, that I want also to write the multiplication as an adding equation.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def adding(num):
summ = 0
for x in range(1, num+1):
    summ += x*x

return summ
```

So far I can show the total result, but I can't figure out a way to print each number being added as I showed above.

Comment: add a `print()` statement

Answer (score 1):

```
def adding(num):
    summ = 0
    for x in range(1, num+1):
        if x > 1:
            print(' + ', end='')
        print('+'.join([str(x) for _ in range(x)]), end='')
        summ += x*x
    print(' =', summ)

    return summ
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help, that seem to have solved it!

Answer (score 0):

This way is not beautiful by any means but I think it illustrates pretty simply what you're trying to do

```
def adding(num):
    summ = 0
    string = ''
    for x in range(1, num + 1):
        if x > 1:
            # append to string x, x times #
            string += ' + ' + (str(x) + '+') * x
            # remove final character in string #
            string = string[:-1]
        else:
            string += str(x)
    summ += x * x

    if x == num:
        string += ' = ' + str(summ)
        print(string)
    return summ
```